# How do I set transmission and receiving frequency band in contiki in CC1200 driver?

Tags: contiki

How do I set transmission and receiving frequency band in contiki in CC1200 driver?

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/dev/cc1200

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Export the right Smart RF settings, I guess. This is potentially a good question, but please, you need to add more details about what did you try and what you want to achieve. (The answer can as well be "impossible" for the specific band you may want.)

Comment: For now I'm voting to close this.